# (Swift) How to make subfolders in one folder

Tags: ios, swift, file, directory, nsfilemanager

I found some code on stackoverflow but I seems like I didnt understand it well:

```
 extension FileManager.SearchPathDirectory {
func createSubFolder(named: String, withIntermediateDirectories: Bool = true) -> Bool {
    var url = FileManager.default.urls(for: self, in: .userDomainMask).first
    url?.appendPathComponent("f/folder1/appName/data")
    print(url)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url!.appendingPathComponent(named), withIntermediateDirectories: withIntermediateDirectories, attributes: nil)
        print(url)
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
}
```

}

using extension:

```
 for index in 1...5 {
                        if FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.desktopDirectory.createSubFolder(named: String(index)) {
                            print("folder successfully created")
                        }
                    }
```

In my app I have a folder 'data'. I want to make 5 new folders called "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" in 'data'.

It prints five times:

> folder successfully created
>   PROBLEM is there are no new folders in `data folder` in my app.

Comment: Addressing the desktop folder in iOS makes no sense. Save your stuff in the documents folder

Comment: I have edited my post few seconds after you commented @vadian. Check it pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like below,

```
extension FileManager.SearchPathDirectory {
    func createSubFolder(named: String, withIntermediateDirectories: Bool = true) -> Bool {
        guard let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: self, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return false }
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url.appendingPathComponent(named), withIntermediateDirectories: withIntermediateDirectories, attributes: nil)
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I have just set withIntermediateDirectories's default value to `true`.

`createIntermediates`: If true, this method creates any nonexistent parent directories as part of creating the directory in url. If false, this method fails if any of the intermediate parent directories does not exist.

Comment: yeah it prints `folder successfully created` 5x but I dont see folders anywhere...

Comment: print your url. if you're in simulator then it will be something like `file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D56B392C-5B71-423E-829C-E17AD760D3E2/data/Containers/Data/Application/6EB7886A-4506-4CE8-B637-1E2C67DD32EC/Desktop/` in your logs. select from `users to last path component (desktop)` and right click on it and -> services -> show in finder

Comment: Here you're creating folders in the desktop directory! So, if you're finding in the document directory then you'll not found it!

Comment: I printed url, it is just like you wrote in the comment. But no folders are created in Desktop..?